# using mogrify on lot of images gives error

Tags: linux, image, ubuntu, mogrify

I am using mogrify to resize the images in a directory using the following command

```
    mogrify -resize 100x100 *.jpg
```

due to the huge number of images, I get the following error

```
    /usr/bin/mogrify: Argument list too long
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` or `xargs` come to mind, eg.

```
find . -name \*.jpg -exec mogrify '{}' -resize 100x100 \;
```

Cheers,

Comment: It didn't help me. Most shells limit the length of the command line. We can get around this by using ImageMagick filename globbing methods. So instead of `mogrify -resize 50% *.jpg` use `mogrify -resize 50% "*.jpg"`. I use this command: `find . -name \*.png -exec mogrify '{}' -format jpg "*.png" \;` It works on 130k+ files.

Answer (score 30):

Actually, the answer is surprisingly simple. Rather than having the shell expand the argument list (which it cannot cope with), let ImageMagick expand the list itself internally, by protecting the arguments from the shell with single quotes.

So, your command becomes:

```
mogrify -resize 100x100 '*.jpg'
```

If the built-in glob expression does not work for you (eg. special file ordering), you may also use the [special character '@'](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#read):

```
mogrify -resize 100x100 @my_jpegs.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

> magick
> [said](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=8435)
>
> ###### Most shells limit the length of the command line. You can get around this by using ImageMagick filename globbing methods. So instead of `mogrify -resize 50% *.jpg` use `mogrify -resize 50% "*.jpg"`

Your case would be

```
mogrify -resize 100x100 "*.jpg"
```